# Regex - is TED video link

Tags: php, regex

I was using this regex:

> `preg_match("/ted\\.com\\/talks\\/(.*)\\.html/i", $arr[0])`

to find out whether the link was pointing to TED.com video page like http://www.ted.com/talks/aparna_rao_art_that_craves_your_attention.html

However, as they released the new version of TED, those videos have now also this format: http://new.ted.com/talks/aparna_rao_art_that_craves_your_attention

and as this:

> `preg_match("/ted\\.com\\/talks\\/(.*)/i", $arr[0])`

matches both (old and new) versions, it also matches this url http://new.ted.com/talks/ which I don't want it to match. How can I set `(.*)` part to be obligatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the part after `/talks/` obligatory, you should use `+` instead of `*`.  This ensures that at least one character appears in the parenthesized group:

```
preg_match("/ted\\.com\\/talks\\/(.+)/i", $arr[0])
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thank you!